# User root already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

i am using JDBC and Hibernate for Connecting to database.

so i am firing select Query to database using JDBC, but when i fire insert Query using Hibernate it gives an exception:

User root already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections.

why so?

is it creating Connection when call session.beginTransaction()

Answer (score 1):

You have exhausted the number of connections you have configured in you DB for root.  I am guessing you are using MySQL (just a hunch based on the userid).  There are several fixes you can try:

1. Create more than one user for all your apps so that you are not competing for connections to the DB
2. Increase the number of connections allowed by your userid, which appears to be `root`
3. Decrease the number of connections your apps are using.  Hopefully you are using a connection pool.

You probably need to check your code to make sure you are closing connections appropriately.  Your code could be orphaning connections over time.

It would be important to note that outside of a dev environment, you really should not be doing any app coding as `root`.  The `root` user has too many privileges, and you open yourself to all sorts of nasty problems from a security aspect.